# How to pass a constructor arg of one bean to a nested bean

Tags: java, spring

I have two classes `A` and `B`. `A` holds `B` as a class field `b`.

`A` has two arguments in its constructor : `public A(C c, D d){`}.

`B` has two arguments in its constructor : `public B(C c, D d){}`.

`A` has a setter for `B`.

in the spring xml, I defined the Bean `B` nested inside `A` :

```
<bean id="B" class="java.util.B"/>

<bean id="A" class="java.util.A>
   <property name="b" ref="B"/>
</bean>
```

if I load `A` as follows:

```
(A)SpringManager.getInstance().loadBean("A",new Object[] {c,d})
```

(assume that `c` and `d` are defined in the class that calles the `loadBean` function)

How do I pass the args that `A` got to `B`'s constructor?

Answer (score 2):

You can't. Either you are in charge or Spring is. What you are doing is wiring objects manually instead of using Spring to manage them. You can't expect Spring to provide magic to enable you to do that.

So you'll have to instantiate `B` first and then pass it to `A`:

```
B b = (B)SpringManager.getInstance().loadBean("B",new Object[] {c,d});
A a = (A)SpringManager.getInstance().loadBean("A",new Object[] {c,d});
a.setB(b);
```

And quite frankly: if you do it like that, I don't see why you are using Spring in the first place.